# Mortgage Calculator/How much can I borrow

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to repair this mortgage calculator, but I really don't understand why the calculation is not working. I need help to sort this out. Or at least someone to make me understand what is wrong with this function. (The calculator has an input for Applicants’ combined annual income and another input for Deposit. The calculator should show results for Maximum property value and Estimated monthly costs).

```
function PMT (rate_per_period, number_of_payments, present_value, future_value, type ) {
        var q = Math.pow(1 + rate_per_period, number_of_payments);
        return (rate_per_period * (future_value + (q * present_value))) / ((-1 + q) * (1 + rate_per_period * (type)));
}

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

        $(".input").keyup(function () {
            var annualIncomeInput = 0;
            var depositInput = 0;
            var annualIncome = 0;
            var deposit = 0;
            var mortgage = 0;
            var propertyValue = 0;
            var monthlyPayments = 0;
            annualIncomeInput = $('#annualIncome').val();
            depositInput = $('#deposit').val();
            annualIncome = parseFloat(annualIncomeInput.replace(/,/g, ''));
            deposit = parseFloat(depositInput.replace(/,/g, ''));
            if (annualIncomeInput && depositInput) {
                if ((deposit / 0.1 - deposit) >= (annualIncome * 4.5)) {
                    mortgage = annualIncome * 4.5;
                    propertyValue = mortgage + deposit;
                } else {
                    propertyValue = deposit / 0.1;
                    mortgage = propertyValue - deposit;
                }
                monthlyPayments = PMT(0.0307/12, 30*12, mortgage, 0, 0).toFixed(2);
            }
            
            propertyValue = parseFloat(propertyValue).toLocaleString();
            monthlyPayments = parseFloat(monthlyPayments).toLocaleString();
            $('#totalHowMuchCanIBorrow').text('£' + propertyValue);
            $('#estimatedCosts').text('£' + monthlyPayments);
            
        })
    })
```

If you need more details please let me know!
Thank you!

Comment: What does it do now that isn't what you expect? It would be helpful if you'd replace the magic numbers with constants named to explain what the numbers are. What's `4.5`, or `0.0307`?

Comment: @Tom W I think that are just some rule of thumb numbers to calculate it. But also don't get what should go wrong exactly. May add an example what the result should be or try to write the formular what it should be and we could help you to find the error in the implementation

Comment: But does it not work at all or just not right not the right result?

Comment: @TomW, PMT = The PMT function is categorized under financial Excel functions. The function helps calculate the total payment (principal and interest) required to settle a loan or an investment with a fixed interest rate over a specific time period. The 0.0307/12 = rate. I found on the internet ( PMT(rate, nper, pv, [fv], [type]) ). The 4.5 means - 4.5 times their salary.

Comment: @Mucksh doesn't work at all...

Comment: Ok you maybe it's the `$(".input")` do your inputs have the css class input or do you mean input tag so want to write `$("input")`? or maybe if not are your script tags in the right order and you load jquery not before it? Did a short test and copy and pastet your code add the few lines of html and it seems to work fine - not sure if the results are right

Comment: @Mucksh hmmmm. Can you show me?

Comment: @Mucksh in code  Jquery is after HTML. I am gonna make some changes and come back with my answer. Thank you!

Comment: If not just leave a small notice and I will post the working html in the answers

Comment: @Mucksh still not working. Can you post yours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works maybe you find the error by comparing it to yours :) didn't changed anything just added the fitting html to it

```js
function PMT(rate_per_period, number_of_payments, present_value, future_value, type) {
  var q = Math.pow(1 + rate_per_period, number_of_payments);
  return (rate_per_period * (future_value + (q * present_value))) / ((-1 + q) * (1 + rate_per_period * (type)));
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  //not sure how your html looks but maybe here you want $("input") and not $(".input") that selects all elements with the css class input that's maybe missing in the html
  $(".input").keyup(function() {
    var annualIncomeInput = 0;
    var depositInput = 0;
    var annualIncome = 0;
    var deposit = 0;
    var mortgage = 0;
    var propertyValue = 0;
    var monthlyPayments = 0;
    annualIncomeInput = $('#annualIncome').val();
    depositInput = $('#deposit').val();
    annualIncome = parseFloat(annualIncomeInput.replace(/,/g, ''));
    deposit = parseFloat(depositInput.replace(/,/g, ''));
    if (annualIncomeInput && depositInput) {
      if ((deposit / 0.1 - deposit) >= (annualIncome * 4.5)) {
        mortgage = annualIncome * 4.5;
        propertyValue = mortgage + deposit;
      } else {
        propertyValue = deposit / 0.1;
        mortgage = propertyValue - deposit;
      }
      monthlyPayments = PMT(0.0307 / 12, 30 * 12, mortgage, 0, 0).toFixed(2);
    }

    propertyValue = parseFloat(propertyValue).toLocaleString();
    monthlyPayments = parseFloat(monthlyPayments).toLocaleString();
    $('#totalHowMuchCanIBorrow').text('£' + propertyValue);
    $('#estimatedCosts').text('£' + monthlyPayments);

  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="input" id='annualIncome' type="number">
<input class="input" id='deposit' type="number">
<div id="totalHowMuchCanIBorrow"></div>
<div id="estimatedCosts"></div>
```

Comment: You are precious! You saved my day! Input class was one issue. Another issue - where jquery code was Initialized in HTML. Thank you!